# Comparar números de telefone do dispositivo com um banco de dados

Tags: android, ios, comparação

Olá!

Estou desenvolvendo um app e preciso comprar os números de telefone do dispositivo com uma lista de telefones em um banco de dados, mas os números de telefone podem ser escritos de formas diferentes como descrito no [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164):

```
Number structure for networks
Country Code - cc = 1 to 3 digits
Identification Code = x = 1 to 4 digits
Subscriber Number = maximum = 15 − (cc + x) = 8 to 11 digits
International public telecommunication number for networks (maximum 15 digits)
```

Então no Brasil o número de telefone pode ser escrito como:

Número do usuário:
99999-9999

Código de identificação + Número do usuário
67 99999-9999

Código do país + Código de identificação + Número do usuário
55 67 99999-9999
ou
+55 67 99999-9999

E em outros países o número de telefone pode ser escrito de formas diferentes e ter padrões de numeração diferentes.

Como posso comprar os números do dispositivo com os do banco de dados como fazem o Telegram e o Whatsapp? Eu preciso criar um código para lidar com cada país individualmente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estou usando [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) para Android e [libPhoneNumber-iOS](https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS) para Swift e eles funcionam muito bem.

Para pegar o código de área de um número eu uso `getLengthOfGeographicalAreaCode` desta forma:

```
String nationalSignificantNumber = phoneUtil.getNationalSignificantNumber(number);
int nationalDestinationCodeLength = phoneUtil.getLengthOfNationalDestinationCode(number);

if (nationalDestinationCodeLength > 0) {
nationalDestinationCode = nationalSignificantNumber.substring(0, nationalDestinationCodeLength);
}
```

Para comprar dois números eu uso `isNumberMatch`